# pythonのアレイ中の値のformatについて

Tags: python

ものすごく簡単なことだと思いますが、問題に引っかかってしまっています。

現在python(version 3.6.0)を使い、アレイを作成しております。
テキストファイルから読み込んだ値を、そのままアレイに挿入したいだけのことです。

具体的には、
sample1.txtとsample2.txtがあるとします。

```
sample1.txtには
20035.87109375,23184.52539062
20031.375,23162.98046875
```

が値として入っており、

```
sample2.txtには、
20037.72460938,23142.20117188
20051.09765625,23124.33203125
```

が値として入っていると考えてください。

このファイルを読み込み、最終的には、以下のようなformatでアレイを作成したいです。

```
[
 [[ 20035.87109375  23184.52539062]
  [ 20031.375       23162.98046875]]

 [[ 20037.72460938  23142.20117188]
  [ 20051.09765625  23124.33203125]]
]
```

テキストファイルの値をアレイに挿入することはわかっています。

```
もし数字で挿入しますと、
[20035.87109375, 23184.52539062]
```

のような形になり、

```
もし文字列で挿入しますと、
['20035.87109375 23184.52539062']
```

のような形になってしまいます。
問題は「数字」でも「文字列」でもないformatで挿入したいです（上記の例を参考にしてください）。

もしどのようなフォーマットで入っているのか、またそのやり方をご存知の人がおりましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `[ 20035.87109375  23184.52539062]` のような表記は、どこでご覧になったのでしょうか。Python のリスト表記としては不正な物ですので、質問者さんのやりたい事、期待している事がとらえ難いです。

Comment: 結局何が欲しいのかが分かりません（上の例を見ると単に数値のリストが欲しいように見えるのですけど，そうじゃないんですよね？）．敢えて推察するなら，仰っている "format" の定義が不明ですが，ひょっとしてそこに混乱があったりするのかも．また「アレイ」というのも python でいうどれに当たるのかちょっと不安があります（`[1,2]` は[リストと呼ばれています](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list)）．

Comment: mjy様, Yosh様、返信ありがとうございます。
現在、他の開発者が作成したpythonプロおグラムを少し改良して使おうと思っています。その時のinputデータのフォーマットが`[ 20035.87109375 23184.52539062]`でした。このフォーマットに合うようこちらのデータを書き直すか、それとも使用したいprogramの使用を少し変更するかで迷いました。なるべくエラーがなく操作することを目指して、自分のデータのformatを変更することにしました。Pythonを使っての開発経験は少ないため、もしかしたら経験豊富なpython userでしたら、何かしらの方法があるかと思いましたが、やはり表記はあまり知られていない方法なんですね。

＞[1,2] はリストと呼ばれています
申し訳ないです。以後きおつけます。

Comment: やっぱり「フォーマット」というのが気になります．どうやって確認したものですか，何らかの関数にそういう文字列を渡してるということでしょうか？

Comment: Yosh様、ありがとうございます。

Comment: Yosh様、ありがとうございます。

他の人が開発したprogramでは、「.hdf5」という形式のファイルを読み込んでいます。
`fname = 'sample.hdf5'; 
with tables.File(fname, 'r') as fid:
    conversion here
    DATA1 = fid.get_node('/coordinates/contours')[:]
print (DATA1)`
自分は、このファイル形式を作成せずに、txt fileからデータを直接DATA1に挿入できないかと試していました。単純に汎用性が広がるためです。

.hdf5は一般的かもしれませんが、pythonでの開発経験が少ないので、なるべくこれを使わずにDATA1を作成できればと思っていました。

Comment: あー，`print(DATA1)` の結果が上で書いてある「以下のようなフォーマット」ということでしょうか．`print` の結果というのは基本的に読みやすいように作ってあって，どんなデータ型かの情報がないので，それだけでは「これと同じものを作りたい」っていうときの情報にはなりません．コードをみると [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/file_class.html?highlight=get_node#tables.File.get_node)とかを使っておられるのかと思いますが，可能ならDATA1を作っているコードを載せて，「この DATA1を hdf5 ファイルを経由せずに作りたいのだが」みたいに編集するといいかもしれません．`type(DATA1)` の結果も若干参考にはなります．

Comment: 大変申し訳ありませんでした。こちらの説明不足でした。また、貴重なお時間を使っていただき、大変感謝しています。

＞

Comment: ＞可能ならDATA1を作っているコード
これがないんです。。。今手持ちにあるのはサンプルデータ(sample.hdf5)だけで、その以外のデータが入手できません。上記のprint (DATA1)までのコードしか、sample.hdf5のデータを表示することができていません。なんとかattributeは作りましたが、扱いにくいので、txt fileから直接入力を考えていました。

Comment: テキストファイルからデータを読んだ後、そのデータを何に使いたいのでしょうか。何かの計算に使うのでしょうか。それとも、ただ表示したいだけでしょうか。

Comment: 補足情報はコメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください

Answer (score 2):

出力結果を見るに、numpy.arrayを使用すれば良いのではと推察します。

```
[
 [[ 20035.87109375  23184.52539062]
  [ 20031.375       23162.98046875]
 ]

 [[ 20037.72460938  23142.20117188]
  [ 20051.09765625  23124.33203125]]
]
```

対話シェルで以下のコマンドを入力すると、

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.array([[10, 20], [30, 40]])
>>> print data # python3なら print(data)
```

似たような出力結果が得られます。

```
[[10 20]
 [30 40]]
```

【参考】
・numpy.array — NumPy v1.12 Manual(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
いつもなんとなくlistを使っており、np.arrayとの違いがはっきり理解し切れておりませんでした。[ https://teratail.com/questions/73677 ]のサイトでようやく違いがわかりました。不勉強が一番の問題でした。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

データの後ろに空白を付け加えて、各データの始まる位置（先頭からの文字数）を揃えた文字列にしたいというだけの事のように思われます。

Sample1の１行目のデータをサンプルにすると

```
#本当はSample1.txtから１行読み取るコードだが、代わりに代入文を使っている
firstLineOfSample1 = "20035.87109375,23184.52539062"
splitted = firstLineOfSample1.split(",") # ","で文字列を分割。
# この例では、splitted[0]="20035.87109375",splitted[1]="23184.52539062"というように２分割される。
splitted[0] = splitted[0] + "                " # 空白文字を末尾に追加する。(先頭の１６文字を切り出せるように、１６文字の空白を追加している）
formatted = splitted[0].[:16]+ splitted[1] #１つ目の項目を区切りの空白も含めて１６文字の文字列にし、その後に２つ目の項目を続ける。（.[:16]は、先頭の１６文字を取り出す事を意味する）
# 結果として、formattedには、"20035.87109375  23184.52539062"という文字列が入る
```

このようにすれば２つの数値を含む文字列が得られるので、配列に挿入してゆけば良い。

Comment: ありがとうございます。文字列での取得は可能でしたが、ここで表示したプログラム以降に続くプログラムがあるため、どうしても数字(?)の形で取得する必要がありましたので、こちらで質問させていただきました。
貴重なお時間を使っていただき、大変感謝しております。